Как удалить динамически созданною кнопку в qt
Я создаю динамически кнопки в layout(он создан в ui файле)
if (responseObject.contains("logins")) {
            // Если пришел список пользователей
            QJsonArray loginsArray = responseObject["logins"].toArray();
            qDebug() << "Активные пользователи:";
            for (const QJsonValue &value : loginsArray) {
                QPushButton *loginButton = new QPushButton(value.toString());
                loginButton->setObjectName(value.toString()); // Устанавливаем имя объекта
                layout->addWidget(loginButton);
                qDebug() << "Теперь количество элементов: "  << ui->UsersVerticalLayout->count();

                connect(loginButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [=]() {
                    handleUserButtonClick(loginButton->text());
                });

                qDebug() << value.toString();
            }
        } else if (responseObject.contains("login")) {
            // Если добавляется новый пользователь
            QString login = responseObject["login"].toString();
            qDebug() << "Новый пользователь:" << login;

            QPushButton *loginButton = new QPushButton(login);
            loginButton->setObjectName(login);
            layout->addWidget(new QPushButton(login));

            qDebug() << "Теперь количество элементов: " << ui->UsersVerticalLayout->count();
            connect(loginButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [=]() {
                handleUserButtonClick(loginButton->text());
            });
        }

затем я пытаюсь удалить определенную кнопку(по логину который мне приходит)
void MainWindow::deleteDisconnectUser(const QString& login)
{
    qDebug() << "Попал в удаление кнопки для логина:" << login;
    QPushButton* button = ui->UsersVerticalLayout->findChild<QPushButton*>(login);
    if(button)
    {
        button->hide();
        delete button;
    }
}

я попадаю в удаление, но кнопка не пропадает. Как решить эту проблему. Как я понял, кнопка не становится дочерним виджетом layout, поэтому не может найтись и удалиться. помогите исправить проблему.

После добавления на компоновщика, кнопка становится ребёнком виджета, на котором расположен этот компоновщик. Вы можете искать среди детей этого виджета, но лучше просто пробежаться по всем элементам компоновщика с помощью QLayout::itemAt и QLayout::count и найти кнопку среди них.
